# Hierarchical list of name value pairs in YAML

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

What's the best way to represent a hierarchical list of name value pairs like the following in YAML:

```
name_1: value_1
  subName1_1: subValue1_1 
  subName1_2: subValue1_2 
name_2: value_2
  subName2_1: subValue2_1 
  subName2_2: subValue2_2 
name_3: value_3
  subName3_1: subValue3_1 
  subName3_2: subValue3_2 
name_4: value_4
  subName4_1: subValue4_1 
  subName4_2: subValue4_2
```

I am thinking of the following but not sure if this is the best way or not:

```yaml
-  name_1:
      ID: 1
      subNames:
         -  subName1_1:
               ID: 1
         -  subName1_2:
               ID: 2
-  name_2:
      ID: 2
      subNames:
         -  subName2_1:
               ID: 1
         -  subName2_2:
               ID: 2
```

or I could also do:

```yaml
-   Name: Name_1
    ID: 1
    SubNames:
      - SubName: subName1_1
        ID: 1
      - SubName: subName1_2
        ID: 2

-   Name: Name_2
    ID: 2
    SubNames:
      - SubName: subName2_1
        ID: 1
      - SubName: subName2_2
        ID: 2
```

I need the name_* to be unique as well as their corresponding values as well so I'd prefer something which python can easily consume to validate there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's the [value key](https://yaml.org/type/value) type. It's not part of the standard and defined for YAML 1.1, but it has been designed to solve this problem. It suggests you basically have a value in your mapping named `=` which contains the default value:

```yaml
name_1:
  =: value_1
  subName1_1: subValue1_1 
  subName1_2: subValue1_2 
name_2:
  =: value_2
  subName2_1: subValue2_1 
  subName2_2: subValue2_2 
name_3:
  =: value_3
  subName3_1: subValue3_1 
  subName3_2: subValue3_2 
name_4:
  =: value_4
  subName4_1: subValue4_1 
  subName4_2: subValue4_2
```

Alternatively, you could make the values a list with single key_value pairs:

```yaml
name_1:
  - value_1
  - subName1_1: subValue1_1 
  - subName1_2: subValue1_2 
name_2:
  - value_2
  - subName2_1: subValue2_1 
  - subName2_2: subValue2_2 
name_3:
  - value_3
  - subName3_1: subValue3_1 
  - subName3_2: subValue3_2 
name_4:
  - value_4
  - subName4_1: subValue4_1 
  - subName4_2: subValue4_2
```

You can write this with flow sequences since YAML allows flow sequences to contain single key-value pairs which will be interpreted as implicit mappings:

```yaml
name_1: [value_1,
  subName1_1: subValue1_1,
  subName1_2: subValue1_2]
name_2: [value_2,
  subName2_1: subValue2_1,
  subName2_2: subValue2_2]
name_3: [value_3,
  subName3_1: subValue3_1,
  subName3_2: subValue3_2]
name_4: [value_4,
  subName4_1: subValue4_1,
  subName4_2: subValue4_2]
```

Be aware that when you do this, you can't have any kind of block-style nodes in the subnames, but other flow nodes will be fine.